# exception with jdbc

Tags: jdbc

i'm a beginner with jdbc, i have a DB in sql server and i connected to a java app code when i run it i resive this:

run:
The SQL connection was successful.
JDBC Driver error:Invalid object name 'dbo.categories'.

categories is an entity in my sql server DB
i really can't solve it by myself,every thing is seems to be right!!!

Answer (score 0):

Post your connection URL.  I think it means that your database name is incorrect.

I think the URL ought to look more like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=foo
```

Leave off the `dbo.` and just use `categories` as the name.

Comment: i want to know is it possible to have problem with table in the DB, couse the error the same for all of the tables

Comment: i have an error with writting sql string, here is the right one:ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from DB_Name.dbo.tbale_Name"); but i'm new user cannot set any answer to my question, just i wrote here

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible reasons for this. These could include:

1. The object doesn't belong to dbo
2. The object does belong to dbo, but the user you logged in as doesn't have permission to view it
3. You're connecting to the wrong database

Finding the owner of a table is something like this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE'
```

Comment: i removed the dbo but didn't solve! my url is: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
         "databaseName=DB_Library; user= 'sa'; password= *****"; the db name is correct how can i know that object doesn't belong to dbo?

Comment: no body answer my question and i really need it:( please help

Comment: It's only been 4 hours. If it's that dire, a Google search would have been a lot quicker.

Comment: Dear Isaac Truett! waht do you mean with: table_schema before FROM how can i write dbo in the list of table catalog?

Comment: @Aida In basic SQL syntax you'll find a comma-delimited list of column names between the `SELECT` and `FROM` keywords. In the example I gave, `table_catalog` and `table_scehma` are both column names I turned up doing a few quick Google searches. I don't have a SQL Server instance running to test the query on, but you can run it yourself and see what happens. Just put the name of the name you're looking for in the `WHERE` clause. I don't understand the second part of your last comment.